# Invalid function regex_extract in hive

Tags: hive

Trying to execute query in hive:

```
select regex_extract(col,'regex',1) from tbl;
```

Verified that regex I am using is correct.

Error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10011]: Invalid function regex_extract
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using `regexp_extract` instead of `regex_extract` in Hive.
Below is the right syntax for the regexp_extract:

```
regexp_extract(string subject, string pattern, int index)
```

Below is an example from hive docs

```
regexp_extract('foothebar', 'foo(.*?)(bar)', 2) returns 'bar.'
```